# Как найти число с плавающий точкой в бинарном файле?

Tags: поиск, hex

Есть конфиг, полученный с устройства, он в бинарном виде. Есть зафиксированные значения, снятые во время его работы. Известно, что конфиг не шифрованный. Как отыскать эти значения?

Взял Hex Editor Neo, открываю поиск, ищу значения с двойной точностью, ввожу искомое значение, но редектор не может его найти.

Как правильно искать?

Comment: Сделайте union с float, double и char. Таким образом вы быстро переведёте. (на с, c++)

Comment: Если нет, вот стандарт https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008

Comment: Можно пожалуйста по-подробнее? Где нужно сделать объединение? hex-редактор, насколько я успел увидеть, такие вещи не умеет.

Comment: Ещё можно взять IDA pro, и пробовать "разобрать" файл.

Comment: У дробных чисел (с плавающей точкой) может быть N форматов хранения. Как минмимум, могут быть разные размеры (число байт) на мантиссу и основание. Поэтому просто ищите все варианты, какие сможете придумать.